# Downloading Image with no Extension

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, urllib2, urllib

I have searched a lot but haven't found a good answer on how to use BeautifulSoup and urllib to use a src link and download the image when it is without an extension, for example, the image for the Facebook app icon @ 
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana is https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/ZZPdzvlpK9r_Df9C3M7j1rNRi7hhHRvPhlklJ3lfi5jk86Jd1s0Y5wcQ1QgbVaAP5Q=w300-rw - without an extension.

What library or method should I be using to download such images?

Comment: What do you need to do with the image? If you're simply saving it to disk, why not just rename it to add the extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the image using the img tag using the class name and the src attribute:

```
import requests
import urllib
r = requests.get("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.facebook.katana")
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content)

img = soup.find("img",{"class":"cover-image"})["src"]
urllib.urlretrieve(img,"fb.jpg")
```